# Pair Programming in Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, programming, vim, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

How do you do collaborative code editing, aka pair programming, in the Ubuntu SDK? I heard you can do this in Vim, and I wonder if the Vim functionality in QtCreator makes this possible.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any working solution involving qtcreator.

You could of course set up a tmux/vim solution to collaborate on code edition but there's many features an IDE provides that can't actually be easily shared with your co-writers.

See [[Qt-creator] Collaborative Editing](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-creator/2013-October/002829.html)